# Blazor radio inputs not responsive with bootstrap classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, blazor, blazor-server-side

After adding bootstrap classes to a Blazor `InputRadioGroup`, the radio options are no longer interactive. They to not respond when clicked. When I open the form they are set to the current value but cannot be changed. This did not happen until after I added bootstrap 4.0 `custom-control` classes to the elements.

Without any classes, the radio buttons work:

```
<InputRadioGroup 
    TValue="Guid?"
    Value="guidVal"
    ValueChanged="e => 
    {
        guidVal = e;
    }"
    ValueExpression="() => guidVal">
    <div>
        <InputRadio Value="GUID_CONST_1" />
        <label>First</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <InputRadio Value="GUID_CONST_2" />
        <label>Second</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <InputRadio Value="GUID_CONST_3" />
        <label>Third</label>
    </div>
</InputRadioGroup>
```

When I add the classes, they stop being responsive:

```
<InputRadioGroup 
    TValue="Guid?"
    Value="guidVal"
    ValueChanged="e => 
    {
        guidVal = e;
    }"
    ValueExpression="() => guidVal">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <InputRadio class="custom-control-input" Value="GUID_CONST_1" />
        <label class="custom-control-label">First</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <InputRadio class="custom-control-input" Value="GUID_CONST_1" />
        <label class="custom-control-label">Second</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <InputRadio class="custom-control-input" Value="GUID_CONST_1" />
        <label class="custom-control-label">Third</label>
    </div>
</InputRadioGroup>
```

Wondering what is causing this. I see no errors in the browser console or the Debug output in VS2022 when using the controls.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using the wrong Bootstrap files? (Ref. [Blazorise's Bootstrap 4 Usage documentation](https://blazorise.com/docs/usage/bootstrap/ (note the comment about how Bootstrap and FontAwesome files that by default are included in a newly created Blazor project may result in (quote:) _that some components will not work as expected_))

Comment: @AstridE. I suppose it's possible. This project started out as an MVC app and is doing a slow transition by using Blazor Components in MVC. This, however, is the first time I have encountered any issues with bootstrap classes anywhere. The radio group is styled correctly as well, just not responsive.